# MySQL крашится раз в день, после перезда базы на новый сервер

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mariadb

На старом сервере стояла база данных **MySQL 5.5.56-2.el7**. После того как переехали на новый сервер, сервер sql раз в день перестает работать. Сейчас версия - **Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB**, файл с дампом развернулся без ошибок все работает, но раз в день крушиться. Что может быть ? Прилагаю логи.

```js
180926 15:13:30  InnoDB: Error: page 0 log sequence number 15792442
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 15188817.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
180926 15:13:48  InnoDB: Error: page 410 log sequence number 15681330
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 15209420.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
180926 15:20:50 [Warning] IP address '31.184.193.100' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180926 16:36:59 [Warning] IP address '58.218.56.94' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180926 18:23:40 [Warning] IP address '211.218.126.142' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180926 19:21:30 [Warning] IP address '185.142.236.34' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180926 20:32:38 [Warning] IP address '117.21.191.217' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180926 23:13:20 [Warning] IP address '196.52.43.97' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927  0:48:30 [Warning] IP address '185.234.219.163' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927  0:50:00 [Warning] IP address '185.234.219.169' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927  0:59:58 [Warning] IP address '196.52.43.118' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927  2:28:36 [Warning] IP address '58.221.55.192' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927  6:52:42 [Warning] IP address '185.234.219.166' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927  8:40:56 [Warning] IP address '185.234.219.162' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927  8:45:33 [Warning] IP address '185.234.219.170' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927  8:49:18 [Warning] IP address '185.234.219.164' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927 11:10:11 [Warning] IP address '122.114.180.183' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180927 11:47:07 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
180927 11:47:07 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
180927 11:47:08 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.60-MariaDB) starting as process 4996 ...
180927 11:47:08 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
180927 11:47:08 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)
180927 11:47:08 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 72499200 bytes)
180927 11:47:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180927 11:47:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180927 11:47:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
180927 11:47:08 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180927 11:47:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137756672 bytes) failed; errno 12
180927 11:47:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180927 11:47:08 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
180927 11:47:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
180927 11:47:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
180927 11:47:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
180927 11:47:08 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
180927 11:47:08 [ERROR] Aborting

180927 11:47:08 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

180927 11:47:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

Comment: _cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool_ в настройках размер буфера больше чем реальная память на сервере

Comment: @DmitryKozlov можно узнать какой параметр устанавливает этот размер в майскл? и как можно посмотреть реальную физическую память на сервере?

Comment: `innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 5G` например. Устанавливает размер буфера 5Gb. Может еще сумма всех параметров превышает размер вашей памяти. Можете воспользоваться калькулятором http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/